# Improving the performance of a MYSQL query with a one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

I have a query in my DB that is taking 25 seconds to return results, which is way too long. It seems like it should be pretty simple. Two tables; the main table (document) is a standard table with some data columns, the join table is a mapping table with only two columns (parent_id, division_id). Previously there wasn't an index on the mapping table so I added one and that changed the "explain" to include the index but doesn't seem to have had an impact on the performance.

The query looks like this:

```
explain SELECT DISTINCT doc.*  
FROM document doc  
LEFT JOIN multi_division_mapper divisions ON doc.id = divisions.parent_id  
WHERE doc.clientId = 'SOME_GUID'  
AND (divisions.division_id IS NULL OR divisions.division_id  IN ('SOME_GUID'));
```

and the results of explain are:
[image]

Total number of rows in document: 6720
Total number of rows in mapper: 6173

From what I've been able to gather I need to improve either the "type" or the "extra" to make the query faster. What can I do here?

Create table statements:

```
CREATE TABLE `document` (
   `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
   `addedBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `addedDate` datetime NOT NULL,
   `editedBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `editedDate` datetime NOT NULL,
   `deleted` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `clientId` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
   `departmentId` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
   `documentParentId` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
   `documentParent` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `fileId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `fileUrl` varchar(600) DEFAULT NULL,
   `documentName` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
   `displayName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `documentId` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   `notes` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
   `visibility` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PRIVATE',
   `documentType` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   `restrictDelete` bit(1) NOT NULL,
   `customData` text,
   `releaseDate` datetime NOT NULL,
   `expirationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
   `isApproved` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
   `userSupplier` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
   `complianceCertificateId` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
   `Status` varchar(50) DEFAULT 'NEUTRAL',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `idx_client` (`clientId`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
 
 CREATE TABLE `multi_division_mapper` (
    `parent_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `division_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`parent_id`,`division_id`),
    KEY `idx_parent` (`parent_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: This seems like a query optimization question, so I added that tag. When asking questions like this, it's helpful to readers to include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name>` for each table in your query, so we can see the data types, indexes, and constraints that you have defined. It's the quickest and most clear way of showing that information.

Comment: I added the create tables to the post. @BillKarwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get a more favorable EXPLAIN report in a test by creating the following index:

```
ALTER TABLE multi_division_mapper
  DROP INDEX idx_parent,
  ADD INDEX (division_id, parent_id);
```

I also dropped `idx_parent` because it's redundant; it's a prefix of the primary key.

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | doc | NULL | ref | idx_client | idx_client | 110 | const | 1 | 100.00 | Using temporary |
| 1 | SIMPLE | divisions | NULL | ref | PRIMARY,division_id | division_id | 38 | const | 1 | 100.00 | Using where; Using index; Distinct |

The `type: ref` is better than `type: index`.

The query I tested is slightly different, but I believe it returns the same result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  doc.*   
FROM document doc   
LEFT JOIN multi_division_mapper divisions
  ON doc.id = divisions.parent_id AND divisions.division_id in ('SOME_GUID')  
WHERE doc.clientId = 'SOME_GUID'
```

Comment: Interesting. Just changing the index had no effect on my query. Moving the division ID to the "OR" clause (your query) instead of the "WHERE" (my query) did it though. It also reduced the query time from 24 seconds to 8.